# Intellij Failed to activate JFR synchronization

Tags: intellij-idea, profiling, jfr

Trying to profile my app locally and it isn't working.

It's saying

`Profiling is not supported on java versions prior to 1.8. If you're using oracle jdk prior to version 11, or hotspot jdk prior to version 1.8.0_252, add the -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures VM option.`

However I'm on azul jdk 8 and I've even added the vm option just to be safe, however it's not working. Any idea why?

Comment: Works fine for me with azul-1.8-382 in the latest IDE build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download Try updating the IDE. If the problem remains, upload your project at https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the UploadID here

Comment: Got to the bottom of it. 2023.2 and 2023.2.1 have a bug, downgraded and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij 2023.2 and 2023.2.1 have a bug, downgraded to 2023.1.3 and it works